# java integer equivalent for 'all'

Tags: java

I understand declaring a variable as an int will only expect digits as a value, however I was wondering if there is any possible values out there that would order the int variable to collect 'all'.

For example I have this method/endpoint that collects data and exports results

```
@RequestMapping("/downloadUserAction")
public void downloadUserAction(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(DRAW_PARAM) int drawNum,
        @RequestParam(value=SEARCH_PARAM) String searchString,
        @RequestParam(value=SORT_PARAM) int colNo,
        @RequestParam(value=SORT_ORDER) String sortOrder,
        Model model) throws JSONException, IOException
{   
    settingResponseTypeAndHeader(response);
    response.addCookie(new Cookie("fileDownload", "true")); //left off at testing how many entries in can handle(4k), neeed to do length=all with pagination (maybe help from Danyi)
    String jsonString = adminPageInfo.getAdminInfo(0, 4000, drawNum, searchString, sortOrder, colNo);           //json String with these values
    JSONArray names = new JSONArray(CSV_COLUMN_NAMES_IN_ORDER);
    JSONArray docs = convertToJsonArray(jsonString);
    preparingJsonAsPerCSV(docs);
    String csv = CDL.toString(names, docs);
    StringBuilder builder =  new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(generateCSVColumnHeader()).append("\n").append(csv);
    streamCSVContent(response, builder.toString());
}
```

I am executing and passing in my parameters on this line

```
String jsonString = adminPageInfo.getAdminInfo(0, 4000, drawNum, searchString, sortOrder, colNo);
```

What I am trying to accomplish is instead of passing '0' in the first parameters I want to pass something like 'all' ...same with the second parameter with the '4000' value, or a range such as '1-5'. This might not be possible just asking anyways, thanks

Comment: Would `Integer.MAX_VALUE` be "all" enough?

Comment: You should overload this method to accept required parameters.
Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: There is no specification for an int primitive that would enable the behavior you want.  Your options are to create the semantics you want programmatically or to write a custom class that encapsulates the state and the behavior you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers are intended to represent only numbers. The meaning/interpretation of each specific number in the range is decided by the application developer. What you want is either pass a variable (like a bool) that will fetch all data and ignore the numbers on the parameters or put the parameter as a string and parse possible numbers.

You can also implement a way to get the number of resources you have and then query it through a GET http limiting on this size.

I would suggest you to read about REST API design.

Some resources:

[Oracle DOC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/Integer.html)

[Pagination in REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/pagination-in-the-rest-api)